# Python random number guessing game

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, replay

```
    I'm having issues with this random number guessing game. There are 2 issues: The first issue has to do with the counting of how many tries you have left. it should give you 3 changes but after the 2nd one it goes into my replay_input section where I am asking the user if they want to play again.
```

```
        import random
        # guess the # game
        guess = input("Enter in your numerical guess. ")
        random_number = random.randint(0, 10)
        print(random_number)            # used to display the # drawn to check if code works
        number_of_guess_left = 3
        # this is the main loop where the user gets 3 chances to guess the correct number 
    
        while number_of_guess_left > 0:
            if guess != random_number:
                number_of_guess_left -= 1
                print(f"The number {guess} was an incorrect guess. and you have {number_of_guess_left} guesses left ")
                guess = input("Enter in your numerical guess. ")
            elif number_of_guess_left == 0:
                print("You lose! You have no more chances left.")
            else:
                print("You Win! ")
            break
```

The second part has to do with the replay input, I can't seem to get it to loop back to the beginning to restart the game.

```
        replay_input = input("Yes or No ").lower()
        if replay_input == "yes":
            guess = input("Enter in your numerical guess. ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `break` statement exits a `while` loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp). The code in the loop executes once, hits `break` at the end, and moves on to execute the code after the loop.

You can have the player replay the game by wrapping it in a function which I've called `play_game` below. The `while True` loop at the end (which is outside of `play_game`) will loop until it encounters a `break` statement. The player plays a game once every loop. The looping stops when they enter anything other than "yes" at the replay prompt which will make it hit the `break` statement.

```
import random

def play_game():
    # guess the # game
    guess = input("Enter in your numerical guess. ")
    random_number = random.randint(0, 10)
    print(random_number)            # used to display the # drawn to check if code works
    number_of_guess_left = 3
    # this is the main loop where the user gets 3 chances to guess the correct number 

    while number_of_guess_left > 0:
        if guess != random_number:
            number_of_guess_left -= 1
            print(f"The number {guess} was an incorrect guess. and you have {number_of_guess_left} guesses left ")
            guess = input("Enter in your numerical guess. ")
        elif number_of_guess_left == 0:
            print("You lose! You have no more chances left.")
        else:
            print("You Win! ")


while True:
    play_game()
    replay_input = input("Yes or No ").lower()
    if replay_input != "yes":
        break
```

Comment: thanks, this makes more sense as I was not using the break command. Thanks for telling me why this doesn't work and how to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please focus on the basics first before posting the questions here. Try to debug with tools like https://thonny.org/. However, I updated your code, just check.

```
import random
# guess the # game
random_number = random.randint(0, 10)
print(random_number) 
# don't forget to convert to int       
guess = int(input("Enter in your numerical guess. "))
number_of_guess_left = 3
# this is the main loop where the user gets 3 chances to guess the correct number 

while number_of_guess_left > 0:
    number_of_guess_left -= 1
    if guess == random_number:
      print("You Win! ")
      break
    else:
      if number_of_guess_left == 0:
          print("You lose! You have no more chances left.")
          break
      else:
          print(f"The number {guess} was an incorrect guess. and you have {number_of_guess_left} guesses left ")
          guess = int(input("Enter in your numerical guess. "))
```